# new dataframe based on column from existing python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframes df_A, df_B and df_C from an existing dataframe df based on categorical values in the column category (A,B and C).

This doesn't work

```
df_A = {n: df.ix[rows] 
 for n, rows in enumerate(df.groupby('Category').groups)}
```

Here I get the error "Key Error: A"

(Note: A is one of the categories)

This doesn't work either

```
df_A = np.where(df['Category']=='A')).copy()
```

Here I get the error: "syntax error"

Finally, this doesn't work

```
df_A = np.where(raw[raw['Category']=='A']).copy()
```

"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'"

Thank You

Comment: Post the errors.

Comment: I also see no "df" in your code.

Comment: sorry, had df as data; I changed that and the errors are already included; thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need first [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) because `Category` is column, not `index` if need dictionary :

```
df2 = {n: data[ data['Category'] == rows] 
           for n, rows in enumerate(data.groupby('Category').groups)}
```

Or try remove `groups`:

```
df2 = {n: rows[1] for n, rows in enumerate(data.groupby('Category'))}
```

Sample:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','A','D'],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (data)
   B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A
2  6  9        D

df2 = {n: rows[1] for n, rows in enumerate(data.groupby('Category'))}
print (df2)
{0:    B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A, 1:    B  C Category
2  6  9        D}

df2 = {n: data[ data['Category'] == rows] 
           for n, rows in enumerate(data.groupby('Category').groups)}
print (df2)
{0:    B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A, 1:    B  C Category
2  6  9        D}
```

Solution without `groupby`

```
df2 = {n: data[data['Category'] == rows] for n, rows in enumerate(data['Category'].unique())}
print (df2)
{0:    B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A, 1:    B  C Category
2  6  9        D}
```

---

```
print (df2[0])
   B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A
```

But if need select dict of `DataFrame` by `Category` value:

```
dfs = {n: rows for n, rows in data.groupby('Category')}
print (dfs)
{'A':    B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A, 'D':    B  C Category
2  6  9        D}

print (dfs['A'])
   B  C Category
0  4  7        A
1  5  8        A
```

Comment: Thank you- but doesn't this create dictionaries and not new dataframes? If I have 3 categories, I want to create 3 dataframes, so df_A for category A and df_B for category B etc

Comment: Thank You - dfs is a dictionary, how do I make individual pandas dataframes out of that dictionary by category?

Comment: I am not sure if understand `df1 = dfs['A']`, `df2 = dfs['D']` in my sample